# Infinite scrolling in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, scroll, pagination

I've found a few questions about infinite scrolling already posted, but none were about Silverlight, so I thought I'd ask. I've done some initial searching, but haven't been able to find any reference material on how to implement infinite scrolling in Silverlight.  This is more of a brain-storming exercise so I can get some thoughts on different ways to implement this.

Comment: Is this for displaying data, like using a listbox or datagrid? Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking for something like that?
http://open-pim.com/tmp/scroll/TestPage.html

Here's the source
http://open-pim.com/tmp/scroll/InfiniteScroll.zip

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty close to what I was looking for. I'm interested in how you implemented that.

Comment: No problem. I've published the source.

Answer (score 1):

I've just published some blog posts and a sample which effectively implement infinite scrolling in Silverlight. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902594/how-to-implement-a-lazy-loaded-silverlight-data-grid-without-using-paging/11931522#11931522).