# How to implement a lazy loaded Silverlight data grid without using paging

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, data-virtualization

Using the Business Application template from the brand new released RIA Services, you can see lots of examples using the data grid on top of a `DomainDataSource` in combination with a `DataPager`. The properties PageSize and LoadSize can be used to adjust the amount of data to be displayed in one page and the data that is prefetched in the background.

Now I'd like to have a data grid with a scrollbar and no pager. The underlying `DomainDataSource` should load only the data that is diplayed in the grid. It should trigger another load, when the user scrolls down to items that are not yet in the data context. Is there any sample implementation how to do this?

Comment: Update: Since the topic comes back I'm currently investigating 3rd-party controls. The Infragistics "VirtualCollection" seems to handle this the best way and can be bound to DomainServices - nice stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just published a couple of blog posts ([Part 1](http://blog.hibernatingrhinos.com/12513/data-virtualization-lazy-loading-stealth-pagingndash-whatever-you-want-to-call-it-herersquo-s-how-to-do-it-in-silverlight), [Part 2](http://blog.hibernatingrhinos.com/12514/data-virtualization-in-silverlight-digging-into-virtualcollection)) that give my solution to this problem. I have also posted [a sample](https://github.com/samueldjack/VirtualCollection) to GitHub that implements my own take on the VirtualCollection concept (I don't know how this compares with Infragistics's control, because I haven't used that).

To show how easy it is to use, here are a few snippets from the sample. First, here's how you use [VirtualCollection](https://github.com/samueldjack/VirtualCollection/blob/master/VirtualCollection/VirtualCollection/VirtualCollection.cs), the class that coordinates fetching the data:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private NetflixTitlesSource _source;

    public VirtualCollection<Title> Items { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _source = new NetflixTitlesSource();
        Items = new VirtualCollection<Title>(_source, pageSize: 20, cachedPages: 5);
    }

    protected override void OnViewLoaded()
    {
        Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```

In XAML you simply bind the `Items` property to the `ItemsSource` property of a `ListBox` or `DataGrid`

For each data source you must implement a VirtualCollectionSource. Here's what the two key methods of [NetflixTitlesSource](https://github.com/samueldjack/VirtualCollection/blob/master/VirtualCollection/Demo/NetflixTitlesSource.cs) look like:

```
public class NetflixTitlesSource : VirtualCollectionSource<Title>
{
    protected override Task<int> GetCount()
    {
        return GetQueryResults(0, 1, null)
            .ContinueWith(t => (int)t.Result.TotalCount, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
    }

    protected override Task<IList<Title>> GetPageAsyncOverride(int start, int pageSize, IList<SortDescription> sortDescriptions)
    {
        return GetQueryResults(start, pageSize, sortDescriptions)
            .ContinueWith(t => (IList<Title>)((IEnumerable<Title>)t.Result).ToList(), TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
    }

    private Task<QueryOperationResponse<Title>> GetQueryResults(int start, int pageSize, IList<SortDescription> sortDescriptions)
    {
        // code to query the Netflix OData API
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks promising. I'll definitly check it out. In the meantime we seriously tweaked the sources from infragistics to achive this...

Answer (score 1):

Check out the work that Bea Stollnitz has done on her blog.  Although not a direct answer to your question, she has written quite a bit on UI and data visualization.  Here are a link from her blog that I think might help to get you started:

Data virtualization: http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=344

HTH!

Chris

Comment: Thank you Chris, I finally read it yesterday. You're absolutely right, it is no direct answer but contains some nice proposals.

Comment: That link is broken, but I think this is the same content from Bea: http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/498#.UE8TT42PXQs

Answer (score 1):

It's called stealth paging.  Component One has a sample of their DataGrid that uses Stealth Paging.  As soon as you scroll down, it gets the next page.

http://demo.componentone.com/Silverlight/ControlExplorer/#DataGrid/Stealth%20Paging

Shows the demo, and you can download the sample which show the code.

Hope this helps,

Greg